# Rollback of Prisma Interactive Transaction in NestJS not working when throwing an error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, rollback, prisma

I am using the [prisma ORM](https://www.prisma.io/) and [NestJS](https://nestjs.com/) and I got the following example code:

```
async createMerchant(data: Prisma.MerchantCreateInput): Promise<Merchant> {
  return await this.prisma.$transaction(async (): Promise<Merchant> => {
    await this.prisma.merchant.create({
      data,
    });
    throw new Error(`Some error`);
  });
}
```

I would expect that the transaction is rolled back as I have thrown an error, but it is not, it creates a new database entry.

Here is [the example of the official documentation](https://www.prisma.io/docs/guides/performance-and-optimization/prisma-client-transactions-guide#interactive-transactions-in-preview).

Is this maybe related to the dependency injection of NestJS and that the injected prisma service is not correctly recognizing the error? Or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As example shows you need to use prisma instance that is passed as an argument to your callback function, like that:

```
async createMerchant(data: Prisma.MerchantCreateInput): Promise<Merchant> {
  return await this.prisma.$transaction(async (prisma): Promise<Merchant> => {
    // Not this.prisma, but prisma from argument
    await prisma.merchant.create({
      data,
    });
    throw new Error(`Some error`);
  });
}
```

Comment: Can`t believe that I have not seen this! Thank you!